# HTML + Javascript Button click again to undo

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering how it is possible to make the button undo something too after clicking it. In my scenario just simple formatting of Text(Color,size etc), when you first click it, it formats the text as described in Javascript, but I would like to add a function, that when you click it again, that it undoes that.

```
`<script>    
function myFunction(){    
  document.getElementById("demo").style.fontsize="25px";
  document.getElementById("demo").style.color="#3AF702";
  document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundcolor="red";    
}    
</script>`

<button type="change" onclick="myFunction()">Change!</button>
```

I checked other articles already, which seemed to be related, but I did not get any smarter out of those, so my apologies in advance if it is a dup and thanks for your help!

Comment: Save the old config in an object/local storage before changing it. Set them again on button click.

Comment: in your function, before you do anything else, check the current colour (and/or any of the other attributes) of the button. If it's currently already the value you are changing it to above, then change it back again. (Of course if what it was before is not predictable/hard-coded, then you'll have to have stored that old value beforehand in relation to the button in question.) If it's not the value you want to change it to, then change it to that value, instead. Should be a simple `if/else` block.

Comment: Thanks for responding already so quickly. I think I have to clarify something here. So  the text has no format before clicking the button, after clicking it changes to the above, now I am wondering how can I make the button to have two functions basically. First click, change to the Format X, second click should undo that change.

Comment: you don't need two functions, you need one function which checks the existing values and makes a decision - as I already described.

Comment: Yea, sorry still a beginner :) after seeing the codes below your answer made sense now too! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>    
var flag = true;
function myFunction(){
  let el = document.getElementById("demo");
  el.style.fontsize = flag ? "25px" : "";
  el.style.color= flag ? "#3AF702" : "";
  el.style.backgroundcolor=flag ? "red" : "";   
  flag = !flag; 
}    
</script>`

<button type="change" onclick="myFunction()">Change!</button>
```

Comment: And that is literally what I was looking for!! Thanks a lot :) now its time to understand it lol but it looks very advanced tho

Comment: @Ochitsuku I'm guessing you're maybe referring to the `?...:` bits? That's called a `ternary operator` and is just a shorthand for `if/else` really. If you google "ternary operator javascript" you can read about it.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to add and remove a class

```html
<style>
  .change {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #3AF702;
    background-color="red"
  }
</style>
<script>
  var x = 0;

  function myFunction() {
    if (x == 0) {
      document.getElementById("demo").classList.add("change");
      x = 1;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("demo").classList.remove("change");
      x = 0;
    }
  }
</script>

<button type="change" onclick="myFunction()">Change!</button>
```

Comment: there's no such functions as "addClass" or "removeClass" on an Element in JS. Are you getting confused with jQuery functions?

Comment: Sorry about that. I got too accustom to jQuery. JavaScript does have a way to add classes though `element.classList.add("myclass");`. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var flag = true;
function myFunction(){
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  if (flag) {
    x.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    x.style.color="#3AF702";
    x.style.fontSize="25px"
  } else {
    x.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    x.style.color="#dddddd";
    x.style.fontSize="10px"
  } 
 flag = !flag
}
```

Comment: That works and is a valid solution, still have to check the others :)

Answer (score 1):

Create an object that stores the initial values of your button and a variable which holds the state of it.

```
var state = 0;
var backup = {};
backup.fontSize = document.getElementById("demo").style.fontsize;
backup.color = document.getElementById("demo").style.color;
backup.background = document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundcolor;
```

Now you can easily switch between the backup and the new values like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  if (state == 0) {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.fontsize = "25px";
    document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "#3AF702";
    document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundcolor = "red";
    state = 1;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.fontsize = backup.fontSize;
    document.getElementById("demo").style.color = backup.color;
    document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundcolor = backup.background;
    state = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: This also works but is more complicated imo then Garry man's answer. Probably because I am not familiar with "var" and backups in JS

Comment: @Ochitsuku "var" just declares a variable. And "backups" here isn't a special concept, it's just the name of a variable. Nothing to be afraid of.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction(){
  demo.className = demo.className ? "" : "style"
}
```

```css
.style {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: red;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">Hi!</p>
<button type="change" onclick="myFunction()">Change!</button>
```

Comment: this will work fine as long as the button has no other classes which need to be added to it...